Изменить порядок столбцов в таблице mysql, через phpmyadmin
Как через phpmyadmin, изменить порядок столбцов(полей) в таблице?
Просто перетащить? Работает пока сессия активна...
А так чтобы совсем изменить порядок на всегда?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34682789


А точно надо изменить порядок полей В ТАБЛИЦЕ? Или - в отображении данных на экране? 2) Если всё же именно в таблице - ЗАЧЕМ?


Если в пма есть права на изменения, то тыкайте в Структура таблицы, далее галкой выберите поле нужное, а внизу (после таблицы полей) ткните Изменить. При изменении в последнем столбце выберите после какого поставить.

там при редактировании таблицы еще есть кнопка Переместить поля, можно через нее драг-н-дропом

Спасибо, выручили...

Ну так а главный вопрос - ЗАЧЕМ менять местами поля в таблице?

@SwaD ну при визуальной работе с таблицей - очень удобно ориентироваться. Например в начале поставить часто используемые колонки или наиболее употребимые.. Особенно например в таблицу users решил добавить колонку отчество, которой раньше не было. Чтобы потом вечно вперёд назад не мотать по таблице при просмотре данных - удобно колонку поставить в начало (к имени и фамилии)... Это примерно как обязательные и необязательные аргументы в методах - всё самое нужное важное - должно быть в начале, остальное - далее
